# How to "export" Java application in 32 bit and 64 bit executables (for Windows)

Tags: java, ant, inno-setup, 32bit-64bit, launch4j

We are currently making our Java application (developed with Eclipse) available in a 64-bits version (for Windows) and we're looking for the best approach to also make a 32-bits version available.

Here are the different steps we currently go through (in an automated way, using batch script) to "export" our application in 64-bits:

1. An executable JAR file is created using an ANT task
2. Jar file is packaged in an executable (.exe) file using Launch4J. A 64-bit JRE is also packaged in the executable (to avoid any issues with non-installed Java, etc.)
3. Executable is signed (with signtool)
4. Setup / installer is created (with InnoSetup) and is also signed (with signtool)

The changes that will thus need to take place to make a 32-bit version are (per step):

1. Code needs to be re-compiled in 32-bits and ANT script needs to reference a different SWT library (32bits)
2. A 32-bit JRE needs to be packaged instead and the JRE max memory option (-Xmx) will have a lower value
3. No change
4. No change

Our question is thus: what are the best-practices to make a Java application available both as 64-bits and as 32-bits? Are there any tools / helpers out there? Does our approach make sense?

Many thanks for any help / hint!

Thomas

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. What does it mean "make a Java application available"? Do you just want to have two separate installers? (then I do not understand what the question is about) Or do you want to have one installer that automatically selects and installs  a correct version for a particular platform?

Comment: I'm looking to have 2 different installers and the questions is: are the steps that I described aligned with best-practices? Are there any tools or tips I should be leveraging? Thanks